# JavaScript: Understanding [match] principle

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

New to coding. I don't understand the principle of [match].
I mean;

```
    var wikipediaDontRedirectRegExp = new RegExp("^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)\\.(?:m\\.)?wikipedia\\.(?:com|org)/wiki/(.*)(?:\\?oldformat=true|\\?previous=yes)", "i");
match = requestedURL.match(wikipediaDontRedirectRegExp);
if (match && match.length === 3) {
    lang = match[1];
    page = match[2];
    returnVal.redirectURL = 'http://' + getFullHostName() + '/' + lang + '/' + page;
    returnVal.domain = 'imgur';
    returnVal.autoRedirect = false;
    returnVal.lang = lang;
    return returnVal;
}
```

On this code, I don't understand that match[1] or match[2] refers.
For example, on

> "^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.(?:m\.)?wikipedia\.(?:com|org)/wiki/(.*)(?:\?oldformat=true|\?previous=yes)",
>   "i"

what is match[1], what is match[2] ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you `console.log(match)`? Read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?

Answer (score 0):

Match is referring to the second line statement:
`match = requestedURL.match(wikipediaDontRedirectRegExp);`

This is using the match function to create the variable also named match. The returned value of the match function is an array, so the next two lines are grabbing the first two values out of this array and setting them to `lang` and `page`.

More details on the `.match()` function can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't understand.
`lang = match[1]
page = match[2];`
I understand that; `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]` is match[1], but I don't get the match[2].

Comment: The function `.match()` returns an array of all matches found using the regular expression. `match[2]` is grabbing another match found using the function.

Comment: Could you show me the match[2] on this: `"^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.(?:m\.)?wikipedia\.(?:com|org)/wiki/(.*)(?:\?oldformat=true|\?previous=yes)", "i"` ?

Comment: Ohhhh, you want a breakdown of how the regular expression works then?

Comment: I'm a real newbie.

Comment: I want to build a Safari extension for redirecting img.com urls to 0imgur.com urls. I found a code about it for Wikipedia and try to adapt for imgur. Their's url formats are different.
Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASustainability%2FMeasuring_sustainability%2FArchive_2?oldformat=true
Imgur: https://imgur.com/gallery/LfjkU

So, If I understand how they matched the links, I can adapt the code for imgur.

Comment: Faith Aktas already beat me to it, but here's some additional reading on the markers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have the expression,

```
^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)\\.(?:m\\.)?wikipedia\\.(?:com|org)/wiki/(.*)(?:\\?oldformat=true|\\?previous=yes)
```

The expression is looking for groups like **([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)** or **(.*)** that doesn' have a cancel, a quotion mark in front of it such as **(?: blabla )**.

**Match** is the results you get from the regular expression in your code. For each match, the elements you get in the array from element 1 to the size of the element are these groups.

---

For example, if we try to find the character couples that have space in between and 'u' after the couple, we use the code below.

Ex: Th**e** **qu**ick would return `["e qu", "e", "q"]`.

```
var paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked.';
var regex = /(\w) (\w)u/;
var found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// Would return Array ["e qu", "e", "q"]
```

In `Array ["e qu", "e", "q"]`

The first element is the whole match, and the other elements found[1] and found[2] are the groups (the brackets) that I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. On imgur.com/gallery/BLABLA how can I write the code for take the **BLABLA**. I mean, `var imgurDontRedirectRegExp = new RegExp("^https?://imgur.com)/gallery/(.*)", "i"); match = requestedURL.match(imgurDontRedirectRegExp); if (match && match.length === 2) { page = match[1]; returnVal.redirectURL = 'http://' + getFullHostName() + '/' + page;` I want to redirecting all imgur.com urls to 0imgur.com urls. For this I need to take the characters after /gallery/ to a 'var'.

Comment: It is pretty much the same way. Look for more examples of the regular expressions to understand how they work. Here are some websites that might help https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_regexp.asp, https://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html. Try it out yourself and post another question if you still have any worries with errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, lemme see if I can do a breakdown on this regular expression for you. I'm far from an expert on using RegEx's but I'm sure there's plenty of people on this site who can point out my shortcomings with this.

Expression:
`^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)\\.(?:m\\.)?wikipedia\\.(?:com|org)/wiki/(.*)(?:\\?oldformat=true|\\?previous=yes)`

`^` character essentially having it check if it's a new line or start of input

`http` match should have this in it

`s?` match can optionally have "s" at this part

`://` match should have this in it

`(` begin making a group to save for easy reference later

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]` match most letters, numbers, and special characters

`+` previous defined group should contain one or more characters

`)` closing group marker

`\\.` escape needed to include the `.` character in match

`(?:` create group but do not have this group saved for reference later

`m\\.` match should have "m." in it

`)` closing group marker

`?` previous group made is optional

`wikipedia\\.` match should have "wikipedia." in it

`(?:` create group but do not have this group saved for reference later

`com|org` match "com" or "org", they're interchangeable

`)` closing group marker

`/wiki/` match should have "/wiki/" in it

`(` make a group that is saved for reference later

`.` match letters, numbers, or special characters

`*` include zero or more characters for previous marker

`)` closing group marker

`(?:` create group but do not save it

`\\?` include "?" in match, meaning this is going to check queries put on the URL

`\\?oldformat=true|\\?previous=yes` check if "?oldformat=true" or "?previous=yes" queries are attached

`)` closing group marker

I think that about sums it up. If you have any more questions on it feel free to comment. But the gist of it is, match[1] is going to grab the `([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+)` group and the match[2] is going to grab the `(.*)` group after the `/wiki/` directory portion.